# C++ best mode to code database metadata info

Tags: c++, qt, qtsql

i'm a novice C++ developer.

I would like to develop a simple Library in C++ with Qt to handle the configuration for application using for example SQLite Database, simulating a KEY, VALUE access.

Actually I use SQLite3 with following Tables:

```
Component (ID <int>, Name <string>)
Keys ( COMPONENT_ID <int>, NAME <string>, Type <string>, Value <string>)
```

The library should have method to get and put Key, Value pairs in configuration.

In order to simplify things I'm using the Qt::QSqlRelationalTableModel.

This require to pass some Table and Column names as Strings.

What's the proper way to define those database metadata?

I'd like to avoid using macro or simple constants, and use for example static struct inside main class.

For example a solution like the following:

```
class ConfigurationHandler()
{
  enum ConfigurationTable { COMPONENT_ID, COMPONENT_NAME };
  enum Key_Table { KEY_COMPONENT, KEY_NAME, KEY_TYPE, KEY_VALUE}
  struct ConfigurationTable {
  {
     QString tableName;
     vector<string>;
  }

  static const ConfigurationTable component;
  static const ConfigurationTable keys;
};
```

Is it a viable choice? How to initialize the data structures above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a structure that contains all needed information about the database schema:

```
class DatabaseSchema {
public:
  QString component_table, component_id_field, component_name_field;
  QString keys_table, keys_component_id_field, keys_name_field /*...*/ ;
};

class DatabaseOperations {
public:
 /*...*/
  void set_schema(const DatabaseSchema& schema);

private:
  DatabaseSchema schema;
};
```